# Avoid virus warning while updating VB.net application from website

Tags: vb.net, auto-update

I have a desktop application (VB.net) which checks for updates while starting and if an updated file is available on my website, it downloads to the user's computer (of course if user has turned on automatic update within my application settings). The problem is that as soon as the new file is downloaded, the antivirus shows a prompt that the file is too new and rare, and it asks user to abort the download or continue it. How can I make my application trustworthy and avoid this antivirus prompt?

Comment: Signing your code with a certificate is the standard option. Google will have lots of information.